# pgfpagesuselayout{2 en 1 with notes} when with notes used error message

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

When I run the code below:

```latex
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{handoutWithNotes}
\pgfpagesuselayout{3 on 1 with notes}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
My first slide
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Second one
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Third
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get always the error messages (either with MiKTeX 2.8 or 2.9, either under Windows XP or Windows 10):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...ox { \vskip .05\pageheight 
                                                  Notes\vskip .1\pageheight ...
l.6 \begin{document}
```

Can some people help me? I want to put beamer slides on the first column and the lines for notes on the second column. Are there other methods?

Comment: I get exactly the same!

Comment: This problem has been fixed in the mean time, see https://github.com/gdiepen/latexbeamer-handoutWithNotes/issues/4

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I cannot test this suggestion, but I solved a similar issue by

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
```